# Polarization sum in FeynCalc

Tags: physics, feyncalc

I think I know how to sum over final state fermion spins (`FermionSpinSum[...]`?) but what is the analog expression (in FeynCalc) if you have two or more polarization vectors? I know the relation in real life but how do you implement it in FeynCalc? PolarizationSum[k,m] is not good enough because in this case you have to manually enter it. Perhaps a replacement of some kind i.e. replace `PolarizationVector[a,b]ComplexConjugate[PolarizationVector[c,d]]` with `PolarizationSum[...]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DoPolarizationSums is your friend.

```
?DoPolarizationSums
```

> DoPolarizationSums[exp,k,n] sums over physical (transverse)
>   polarizations of external massless vector bosons with momentum k. \
>   Here, n is an auxiliary four
>   vector that goes into the gauge-dependent polarization sum to ensure \
>   that we are
>   summing only over physical polarizations.
>
> DoPolarizationSums[exp,k,0] replaces the polarization sum of external \
>   massless vector
>   bosons with momentum k by -g(mu,nu). This corresponds to summing over \
>   all four
>   physical and unphysical polarizations.
>
> DoPolarizationSums[exp,k] sums over polarizations
>   of external massive vector bosons with momentum k and mass k^2.

Lots of tree level QED and QCD examples that use `DoPolarizationSums` can be found here:

https://github.com/FeynCalc/feyncalc/tree/master/FeynCalc/Examples/QED

https://github.com/FeynCalc/feyncalc/tree/master/FeynCalc/Examples/QCD

Comment: Awesome, the new `DoPolarizationSums` (FeynCalc 9.0.0) can also handle massive vectors...